# How to give a anchor link the hover style for when it is the selected link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm probably not explaining this very well and I know there is a css property that handles this, I just cant remember its name. I have a menu and I want currently selected link that corresponds to the page being viewed be styled in a way that shows the user what page he is on.

Thanks

Comment: You're mistaken, you cannot do this purely with CSS.

Comment: You might be thinking of `a:active` (and by extension `a:active:hover`) but that's not quite the same thing. Typically this is done by adding a class to the link that points to the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by editing the HTML of each page and adding a `class` to the relevant link. For example, if you are on the `index.html` page, your markup might look something like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
<a href="news.html">News</a>
<a href="about.html">About Us</a>
```

But if you were on the `news.html` page, it would look something like this:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="news.html" class="current">News</a>
<a href="about.html">About Us</a>
```

Notice how the `class` is only on the current page. You then style `current` however you see fit in your CSS file like so:

```
.current {
   ...
}
```